# How does Tor protects from the list of Digital Finger Print

Tags: configuration, security, fingerprinting, information-leaks

I have heard that Tor protects users from sites that try to fingerprint browsing history with its integration of **NoScript**. But it's not completely secure as some researchers claims.

Does Tor really protects over these list of Fingerprint Vectors. They are as follows

> ```
> 1. User Agent(User-Agent header)
> 2. Screen resolution (screen.height, screen.width) 
> 3. Window size (window.height, window.width) 
> 4. Pixel density (screen.pixelDepth)
> 5. Color depth (screen.colorDepth)
> 6. Timezone ((new Date()).getTimezoneOffset())
> 7. plugins installed
> 8. fonts installed
> 9. navigator.platform
> 10. Flash/Java version from JavaScript
> 11. webgl (graphics hardware & driver version)
> 12. canvas
> 13. Media devices (navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices())
> 14. Language
> 15. session storage supported
> 16. local storage supported
> 17. codecs
> 18. DRM
> 19. DNT enabled
> 20. indexDB supported
> ```

Do we need to install any other plugin/addons in order to encounter above lists.
Apart from Tor browser, in case with any other normal browser how should we need to prevent them?

Could someone can explain in brief regarding how does tor protects with regarding 
to the above list of Fingerprint vectors? In case if not what must be the necessary configurations needs to be applied to make it completely secure?

Comment: You can never make it “completely secure”. The Tor Browser team tries to prevent fingerprinting as much as they can without ruining the user experience, but browser fingerprinting is still an active area of research. Disabling JavaScript should help. I don’t know how well the Tor Browser deals with all of those in your list. If you want to have some idea about how your browser compares to other users, checkout EFF’s panopticlick if you haven’t already: https://panopticlick.eff.org/

Comment: @Steve Ya have checked in the past the results were:

[Panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org)Yes! You have strong protection against Web tracking.

[Amiunique](https://amiunique.org/fp) Almost! (You can most certainly be tracked.), [browserplugs](https://www.browserplugs.com) and

[Fingerprint](https://fingerprint.pet-portal.eu/)